# In Django how do I notify a parent when a child is saved in a foreign key relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following two models:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Some help.')
    entity = models.ForeignKey(CancellationEntity)
    ...


class Cancellation(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now().date())
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...
```

I would like the Activity model to be aware when a Cancellation related to it is saved (both inserted or updated).

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want to look into is [Django's signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) (check out [this page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) too), specifically the model signals--more specifically, the **post_save** signal. Signals are Django's version of a plugin/hook system. The post_save signal gets sent every time a model is saved, whether it's updated or created (and it'll let you know if it was created). This is how you'd use signals to get notified when an Activity has a Cancellation

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Some help.')
    entity = models.ForeignKey(CancellationEntity)

    @classmethod
    def cancellation_occurred (sender, instance, created, raw):
        # grab the current instance of Activity
        self = instance.activity_set.all()[0]
        # do something
    ...


class Cancellation(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now().date())
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...

post_save.connect(Activity.cancellation_occurred, sender=Cancellation)
```

Comment: Your `cancellation_occurred` method should take `**kargs`. e.g `cancellation_occurred(sender, instance, created, raw, **kargs`.

You can find this specified on the [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#receiver-functions) page in the second/third paragraph of _receiver functions_

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with the following?

```
class Cancellation( models.Model ):
    blah
    blah
    def save( self, **kw ):
        for a in self.activity_set.all():
            a.somethingChanged( self )
        super( Cancellation, self ).save( **kw )
```

It would allow you to to control the notification among models very precisely.  In a way, this is the canonical "Why is OO so good?" question.  I think OO is good precisely because your collection of Cancellation and Activity objects can cooperate fully.

Comment: Considering `Activity` and `Cancellation` are closely related I think this is a better solution.

Comment: So you write that for every child table. and probably later refactor it to a base class?

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you can use a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) to update the parent when a child is changed. To do this, you need to create a signal that listens for the `post_save` signal of the child model and sends a signal to update the parent model.

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Some help.')
    entity = models.ForeignKey(CancellationEntity)


class Cancellation(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now().date())
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Cancellation)
def update_activity(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    activity= instance.activity
    activity.save()
```

In the code above, we're creating a signal function to listen to the `post_save` signal of the `Cancellation` model. The `update_activity` function takes the `sender` and `instance` parameters where `sender` is the class of the model that sent the signal, and `instance` is the instance of the model that was saved. The `kwargs` parameter contains any additional keyword arguments.

When a `Cancellation` object is saved, the `sender` parameter is set to `Cancellation`, and the `instance` parameter is set to the `Cancellation` instance that was saved. The `update_activity` function takes the `activity` object and saves it, triggering its `post_save` signal if any.

Now, when a `Cancellation` object is saved, the `update_activity` function updates the `Activity` model as well.