# Child model updates Parent model in Django ForeignKey relationship

Tags: django

Assuming the following models schema,

## Parent model:

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

## One of many child models:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.ON_CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

My goals is the following: to have a start field of parent model that is always updated when any child model is modified.
Basically, if the timestamp of a newly data instance is older than the start field I want the start field to be updated to that instance timestamp value. In the case of deletion of the data instance which is the oldest time reference point I want batch start field to be updated to the second oldest. Vice-versa for the end field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible way to do this is to add post or pre-save signal of relative models and Update your necessary fields according to this. Django official documentation for signal, [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/). I want to add another [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html), one of the best blog post i have seen regarding django signal.

#### Edit for André Guerra response

One of easiest way to do a get call and bring Batch instance. What i want to say

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Data)
def on_batch_child_saving(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    batch_instance = Batch.objects.get(pk=instance.batch)
    if (instance.timestamp < batch_instance.start): 
        batch_instance.start = instance.timestamp
        batch_instance.save()

    elif (instance.timestamp > batch_instance.end):
        batch_instance.end = instance.timestamp
        batch_instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shakil suggestion, I come up with this: (my doubt here was on how to save the parent model)

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Data)
def on_batch_child_saving(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    if (instance.timestamp < instance.batch.start): 
        instance.batch.start = instance.timestamp
        instance.batch.save()

    elif (instance.timestamp > instance.batch.end):
        instance.batch.end = instance.timestamp
        instance.batch.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you can use a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) to update the parent when a child is changed. To do this, you need to create a signal that listens for the `post_save` signal of the child model and sends a signal to update the parent model.

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class Batch(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

class Data(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.ON_CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

@receiver(post_save,sender=Data)
def update_batch(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    batch = instance.batch
    if (instance.timestamp < batch.start): 
        batch.start = instance.timestamp

    elif (instance.timestamp > batch.end):
        batch.end = instance.timestamp

    batch.save()
```

For more information, you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76545146/15863196).