# How to Dynamically Add the one or more attribute(FIELD) value of one model to Another model in same app

Tags: python, django, model, relation

I Want to get user and assessment from TestUsers Model (username, Assessment) to AssignmentAssessment Model (user, assessment) respectively, whenever an instance of TabletUser is created.

```
class TabletUsers(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    paassword = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    District = models.ManyToManyField(District)
    Assessment = models.ManyToManyField(MasterAssessmentType)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + self.lastname


class AssignedAssessment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(TabletUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assessment = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Comment: Here is a post of almost similar problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262168/child-model-updates-parent-model-in-django-foreignkey-relationship/53262410#53262410)